# Warning: mysql_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

How to solve this error using wampserver, **Warning: mysql_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given**

```
<?php
  session_start();
?>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="my_layout.css"  type="text/css" />
<title>Phone Book Project</title>
<body class="my_body">
        <div id="my_divition">  

      <?php
       $connect=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","phonebook");

                $username=$_POST['username'];
                $password=$_POST['password'];
                $sql="select * from members where username='$username' AND password='$password'";
                 if($result=mysqli_query($connect,$sql)){  
                 $number=mysqli_num_rows($result);
                 }
                  if($number>0)
                 {


                   $id=mysql_result($result,0,"id");            
                    $_SESSION['id']=$id;
                    session_register('id');

                    include('Control.php');
                }
                else 
                 echo"<h1> <br /><br />Sorry : invalid entery <br /><br /></h1><a href=index.php >
                 go  back </a>";

           ?>
```

Comment: You're mixing MySQL APIs, you can't do that. Use `mysqli_` exclusively.

Comment: Try `$id = mysqli_data_seek($result, 0);`

Comment: Or see http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/286201-help-updating-mysql-result-from-mysql-to-mysqli/ there's a few ways in there.

Comment: @Nikunj do you solved your problem? Don't forget check one answer as correct ;-)

Comment: In which line is the error?

Comment: @Nikunj as you says that my answer help you don't forget check it as correct ;-)