# mysql_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

As a part of a login system I need to check if the username exists in the database so I created a query that checks if the username the user entered already exists.

With `mysql_result` I check if the id is larger as null. If yes: user exists and if not the user doesn't exist. But here it goes wrong and wampserver gives me this error:

> Warning: mysql_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in users.php on line 6

```
function user_exists($username){
    global $user_db;
    $username = sanitize($username);
    $query = mysqli_query($user_db , "SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'");
    $result = mysql_result($query, 0); //line 6
    if(!$result){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

and this is the code that calls that function:

```
if(user_exists('name') === true){
    echo 'exists';
}

$user_db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","databaseName");
```

What did I try:
if I do this: `mysqli_result($result,0,"id");` I get this error: `Call to undefined function mysqli_result()`.
got this suggestion from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28734848/warning-mysql-result-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-object-given) question

All the answers on questions like mine say that you should not use `mysql`
and `mysqli` both but only one of them but when I only use `mysli` I get the error like I told one paragraph above this one.

So can somebody tell me how to fix this.

Comment: What is `$user_db` is your code??

Comment: @Saty that is the database connect variable

Comment: @Vinc199789 you are mixing `mysql_` with `mysqli_` .... `$query = mysqli_query` `$result = mysql_result`

Comment: @Vinc199789 take time and read the correct manual : http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing mysql and mysqli a bit. There is no function mysqli_result() in mysqli driver. However I found a solution to your problem. From comment in PHP documentation:

> Converting an old project from using the mysql extension to the mysqli
>   extension, I found the most annoying change to be the lack of a
>   corresponding mysql_result function in mysqli. While mysql_result is a
>   generally terrible function, it was useful for fetching a single
>   result field *value* from a result set (for example, if looking up a
>   user's ID).
>
> The behavior of mysql_result is approximated here, though you may want
>   to name it something other than mysqli_result so as to avoid thinking
>   it's an actual, built-in function.

The code:

```
<?php  function mysqli_result($res, $row, $field=0) { 
      $res->data_seek($row); 
      $datarow = $res->fetch_array(); 
      return $datarow[$field];  }  
?>
```

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php

Comment: How Do I store the result in a variable do that I can check in in a if statement

Comment: Just like you are doing in your code, just replace `$result = mysql_result($query, 0);` with `$result = mysqli_result($query, 0);`

Comment: Thanks that works. I didn't understand your answer. I first thought I needed to add the function or the other one butnow I understand it. So the problem was that `mysqli_result` was not declared. Are there more functions like this one that need to be declared in a function in your code?

Comment: Actually you needed to add the function because is not built-in and is meant   for backwards compatibility with old deprecated mysql driver.

Comment: But are there more thing like `mysqli_result` that need their own function?